# sizeof and pass-by-reference

Tags: c++, templates, sizeof

I am hoping that someone can explain the following behaviour.

Suppose I am trying to implement a function which determines the length of any array, but want to avoid using macros. For e.g

```
#define array_length(x) ( sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0]) )
```

Given that the function must work with any parameter type, I must use templates.

My first try looked something like this.

```
template <typename T>
inline size_t
array_length(const T argument) {
    return sizeof(argument) / sizeof(argument[0]);
}
```

This doesn't work because the argument is treated as a pointer. Once T is changed to T& everything works dandy.

I am wondering if anyone can say something about what is happening at the level of language implementation. For example, what extra information is passed to a function when references are used as function arguments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's consider two function templates:

```
template <typename T> void f(T);
template <typename T> void g(T const&);
```

And let's say we have an array:

```
int a[10];
```

What happens when we call `f(a);`?  Since we don't explicitly provide an argument to the template, argument deduction kicks in and the compiler tries to figure out what `T` is based on the argument.  The argument is of type `int[10]`.  `T` will never be deduced to be a reference type and you cannot pass an array by value, so the array-to-pointer implicit conversion takes place and `T` is deduced to be `int*`.

What happens when we call `g(a);`?  Again, argument deduction is used to determine what `T` is.  The parameter is of type *reference to `T`*, though, so `T` can be deduced directly to be `int[10]` and the array-to-pointer conversion does not take place.

Note that the best solution to finding the length of an array is to explicitly require that the template get an array:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
std::size_t array_length(T const (&)[N]) { return N; }
```

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there is no good way to do that outside of macros. Which is why I'd rather use `std::array` (new class in C++0x, evolved from [boost::array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/array.html), which is available also for "old" C++) or a `std::vector`.

Comment: +1 for `std::array`, but as to requiring macros: OP's own attempt is way inferior to the templates shown by other answers.

Answer (score 1):

I know you're looking for more technical info, but you can get the # of elements in an array without macros using template argument deduction:

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
size_t ElementCount(const T (&x)[N])
{
    return N;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
int x[15];
size_t elements = ElementCount(x);
```